# Why posting new BuiltFileObject clears array of BuiltFileObject from built app? Did i miss anything?

Tags: ios, xamarin, sdk, built.io, built.io-backend

I am fetching `BuiltClass` from my built app through SDK and I get list of built file objects in it like  e.g: `List<BuiltFileObject>`

Below listed properties I get from `BuiltFileObject`:
`app_user_object_uid, content_type,file_size,filename, tags[], uid ,url`

Now if I upload any file then I get same `BuiltFileObject` with all properties and I inserted that file object in `List<BuiltFileObject>` and saved `BuiltClass`. But in response I don't get list of `BuiltFile` Objects.

Am I missing anything in save call?

Comment: Can you post some more example code? What does your BuiltClass subclass look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the upload before your save your BuiltClass. See the [documentation for Uploads](https://docs.built.io/guide#uploads).